# Trying to remove Text from Textbox in userform (Text = Label.Caption) but only one at a time as multiple could be entered

Tags: vba, text

```
Private Sub Option_Remove_device_Click()

 If Uf_Device_selection.Option_Add_device.Value = True Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").range("B2") = "Add"
     Else
      Sheets("Sheet1").range("B2") = "Remove"
    End If

End Sub
```

…

```
    Private Sub Label_01_Click()
    If Uf_Device_selection.Option_Add_device.Value = True Then
        Text_Device_list = Label_01.Caption + " , " + Text_Device_list.Value
    Else
       Text_Device_list.Text = LCase(Trim(Label_01.Caption)) ''''this is the section i am stuck on '''
    End If

End Sub
```

…

```
Private Sub Label_02_Click()
    If Uf_Device_selection.Option_Add_device.Value = True Then

    Text_Device_list = Label_02.Caption + " , " + Text_Device_list.Value
Else
     Text_Device_list.Text = LCase(Trim(Label_02.Caption))''''this is the section i am stuck on '''
End If

End Sub
```

when using the trim it removes all but the Label. Caption I have clicked on, I just need it to work the other way around. e.g.

Text box shows:
Label_02.Caption , Label_02.Caption , Label_02.Caption, Label_01.Caption, Label_02.Caption
and now I want to remove only one Label_02.Caption from the text box by clicking Label_02

any help you much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub La02_Click()
If Uf_Device_selection.Option_Add_device.Value = True Then

    Text_Device_list = La02.Caption + " , " + Text_Device_list.Value
Else
    Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, La02.Caption + " , ", "", 1, 1)
End If
```

End Sub

> So I just had to use a Replace function which has sorted this piece of code for me. Now when the remove option is selected then you can remove one (La.Caption) at a time.